# NSPredicate where all objects in a one-to-many fufill a requirement

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

Lets say I have this model:

- Bars have a one-to-many relationship to Foos
- All foos have a property called ishappy

Is it possible to set up a NSPredicate on Bars to which would be the equivalent of the english sentence "Give me all Bars that have >= 1 foos, but only if all the foos areHappy"?

I wish I could give some code but all things DB are my weakest point and I am stuck at this point. I could get the results and filter them manually of course, but I would like to have it all in NSPredicate if possible (for various reasons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work (untested):

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"foos.@count >= 1 AND (ALL foos.ishappy == YES)"]
```

*Update:* When testing this I got an exception when executing the fetch request.
It seems that Core Data has problems with the "ALL" aggregate.
As a workaround, a SUBQUERY can be used:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"foos.@count >= 1 AND SUBQUERY(foos, $f, $f.ishappy == NO).@count == 0"];
```

Comment: @GaganSingh: You are welcome. - But the first solution did not work when I tested it. I have updated the answer with an alternative predicate that should work in any case.

Comment: Ahh interesting, I extracted the logic and used @"SELF.foos.@count >= 1 AND (ANY foos.isHappy == NO)" for my real life example. (I ended up really needing my Bar if at least 1 foo was happy.) Its interesting that "ALL" does not work. But thank you as well for the update as I'm sure that will be handy in the future.